# Implicit conversion issue with XmlElement ad XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlnodelist

I have a Xml document that I want to convert into a XnlNodeList using a linq query. Now, neither Xml nor Linq are something know well. The error I'm getting is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Xml.XmlElement>' to 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`.

```
XmlNodeList abTestDocx = abTestDoc.GetElementsByTagName("FS").OfType<XmlElement>().OrderBy(FS => FS.GetAttribute("label"));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't generally create `XmlNodeList` instances yourself. Do you really *need* one though? If you just need to iterate over the nodes, just assign it to an `IEnumerable<XmlElement>`:

```
IEnumerable<XmlElement> abTestDocx = abTestDoc
     .GetElementsByTagName("FS")
     .OfType<XmlElement>()
     .OrderBy(fs => fs.GetAttribute("label"));
```

Note that using LINQ to XML is generally nicer than the old `XmlDocument` API. Then you'd just need:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> abTestDocx = doc
     .Descendants("FS")
     .OrderBy(fs => (string) fs.Attribute("label"));
```

... and all kinds of other things would be simpler too. LINQ to XML is lovely :)

Comment: I need to sort the `XmlNodeList`. The original code was `XmlNodeList abTestFieldNodes = abTestDoc.SelectNodes("//foo/bar");` as later in the code we look for `XmlElement` attributres, etc. So this seemed like "simple" solution.

Comment: @Risho: Why do you require it to be an `XmlNodeList` afterwards? What are you doing with it?

Comment: This is in MVC environment and we have a Xml file that is used like a datasource to create and poplulate dropdownlists. We loop through the `XmlNodeList`, and compare the current node's id and name against a hash table that contains data. If we have a match we buld the html controls, etc.

Comment: @Risho: Well why can't you loop through an `IEnumerable<XmlElement>` instead? That's my point - don't you just need a sequence of nodes?

Comment: I will have to look into as I haven't worked with this before. Thanks for your input!